# How to implement mongo project stage compute in java driver?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongodb-java, mongodb-java-3.3.0, mongodb-java-3.8

I want to compute a new field  using project stage in aggregation pipeline in Java driver.
I want create new field by just multiplying value (that is coming from previous stages) with 100.

```
 Bson projectGroup=   Aggregates.project(
                    Projections.fields(
                    Projections.computed("computed", "{'$multiply':[100,'value']}}}")
                    )
                    );
```

Result has the computed field but its value is static expression

> ""{'$multiply':[100,'value']}}}""

How to get run the expression and get the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question for others.
We need to parse the expression as follows

```
 Bson projectGroup=   Aggregates.project(
                Projections.fields(
                Projections.computed("computed",  Document.parse("{'$multiply':[100,'value']}}}"))
                )
                );
```